# Regexp - How to find capital letters in MySQL only

Tags: mysql, regex

I'am trying to delete words which have 2 capital letters consecutively with MySQL. Like: "ABC", "AA", "NBC". No others.

The following query doesn't work (it finds all words, which have 2 letters)

```
  WHERE names REGEXP '[A-Z][A-Z]'
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `WHERE names REGEXP '[A-Z]{2,}'` maybe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
WHERE names REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]{2}'
```

> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 3):

This pattern matches two or more leading uppercase characters:

```
WHERE names REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]{2,}';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`([A-Z]+)`

it will match all capital words

Comment: 1. it would match only capital **letters** 2. it will match all letters, as long as case-insensitive collation is used